# GNOME terminal does not display UTF-8 characters

Tags: linux, gnome

I cannot get GNOME terminal to display UTF-8 characters which shows up as squares.

Menu bar: 'Terminal->character encoding' is set to UTF-8.

env var LANG is en_US.UTF-8.

The same file can be displayed properly in emacs.

Searched for similar questions here, but can't find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

GNOME terminal version: 3.28.2